# Why is Boruch Hashem Leolam not said in Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz, ashkenazi, maariv

Outside of Israel we say ...ברוך ד' לעולם after השכיבנו by Maariv. Why is this part of tefilah not said in Israel (or: why *is* this said outside Israel)?

Comment: BTW, in the Sfardi minhag, it's not said anywhere, and in the Italian and Hungarian minhagim, it's said in Israel too.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that Chasidim who say it say it in E"Y too.

Comment: The question should be, why is it said outside of Israel? From the gemara in M. Brachot, it is clear that there being someich geulah l'tefilah is very important.

Comment: @yoel I davened in many difference Chassish shuls in E"Y, and have (so far) never seen it being said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ashkenazim in Eretz Yisroel generally follow the customs of the GR"A.  One of his customs was omitting *Boruch HaShem Leolam* as an unnecessary interruption between the blessings following the Shema and the Shemone Esre.

I would cite Siddur HaGR"A as a source except that I don't have a copy to confirm.

As for why it *is* said, [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9802/saying-baruch-hashem-lolam-without-a-minyan) might be a good place to start.

Comment: The [Sidur HaGra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21127&st=&pgnum=221) does include it, and the instructions above it don't mention anything about not saying it.

Comment: @ba, the Siddur Ezor Eliyohu (Gr"a) does not include it.